# Deleting specific rows from file.dat

Tags: python, loops, readline, with-statement

I have a dat file called ell_***old.dat that contains these rows:

```
saibh \x00\x00\x00\x00\ usodbh
isub hf
asihbf sf
dga\x00\x00\ghsd
iasbh oi
ioehr g
ashb sd \x00\x00\s
su\x00\ahbf
xzfbas sg
\x00\sagag sf sef
```

What I was trying to do is to delete all the rows that contains the character "\00". There are already some solved questions about this topic, but they do not treat cases in which the character is "inside" the row. This is what I tried:

```
with open("/home/lome/ell_***_old.dat", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

with open("/home/lome/ell_***_old.dat", "w") as file:
    for line in lines:
        if "\x00" not in line:
            file.write(line.rstrip() + '\n')
```

but this script is basically rewriting the dat files with the same lines, including the ones with the character "\00". What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure the file actually contains `\x00` as a single character, and not as 4 characters?

Comment: @ScottHunter thank you for your answer. Could you please explain further?

Comment: To read or write binary file use open with "b" mode: "rb", "wb"

Comment: if the file literally contains the backslash character \\ and x and 0 0 - 4 characters in total, just escape the backslash in the Python code: `if "\\x00" not in line:` this will match the literal sequence, not the escaped representation of a single character with code "0"

Comment: What's the output of `xxd yourfile` ?